# Laravel Search results

Tags: php, search, laravel-4

I have the following issue? When you do a search for foo on our platform you get a search result with a blank page. I would like to put a search result if a user type in a search query that is not on our platform with a snarky little response like "Sorry but there are no foo's on our platform".

In our searchcontroller.php under controllers i have the following

```
<?php

class SearchController extends BaseController
{
public function getIndex()
{
    $search = Request::get('q');
    if (empty($search)) {
        return Redirect::to('gallery');
    }
    $extends = explode(' ', $search);


    $images = Images::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->orWhere('tags', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')->orWhere('category', '=', $search)
        ->where('deleted_at', '=', NULL)->where('approved','=',DB::raw(1))->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');

    foreach ($extends as $extend) {
        $images->orWhere('tags', 'LIKE', '%' . $extend . '%')
            ->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('image_description', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
    }
    $images = $images->paginate(30);

    return View::make('gallery/index')
        ->with('images', $images)
        ->with('title', t('Searching for').' "' . ucfirst($search) . '"');

}
```

}

Comment: "I would like to…" Then do it. What's the problem, specifically?

Answer (score 0):

In your view you'd do something like this:

```
@if ($images->isEmpty())
    Sorry but we found no search results.
@else
    @foreach ($images as $image)
        <img src="{{ $image }}">
    @endforeach
@endif
```

That's more pseudo code then anything. Basically just check if the `Paginator` instance has any items, if not, show the "no search results" message.